# Populating extra attributes in join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an Event and Unit model, and a join table events_units with an extra attribute "amount", that specifies the amount of units delegated to each event.

Using `some_event.units << some_unit`, will populate the foreign keys, but leave the amount attribute as nil. How do I go about inserting all the values into the join table?

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a model that works with a join table.
Then you gonna have something like this.

```
eu = EventUnit.new
eu.amount = 5

event.event_units << eu
eu.save
```